# css/JavaScript resize div content to fit window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with a lot of images positioned on top of another image.
The position of the smaller images is relative, and the left and top distance is given using px.
When I scale the window, the collection of images moves and stays in the right place. But I want it to also scale when I resize the window. (The ratio of the images should stay the same, but smaller/larger.)
All the images are contained in an overlaying div.

Is there any way for me to do this without having to reposition all the images? (I'm very new to css/JavaScript)

Here's an example of what is happening: https://codepen.io/gwenvere/pen/MWJdvJp
What I want is for the red ball to stay on top of the mountain, but for the mountain and ball to shrink if the window becomes smaller.

Here is an example of the css of one of the smaller images:

```
  position: relative;
  left: 161.7px;
  top: 208.7px;
  width: 79px;
  height: 79px;
  background-color: rgba(56, 152, 236, 0);
  background-image: url('../images/Medium.png');
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The css of the larger image:

```
.image-11 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 148px;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-top: -37px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

css of the overlaying div:

```
.div-block-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  max-height: none;
  max-width: none;
  min-height: auto;
  min-width: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: rgba(83, 39, 39, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), either by editing your question and creating a snippet (there's a snippet button in the text editor), or in an external tool like Codepen? I'm afraid the CSS alone isn't enough to help.

Comment: try adding `object-fit: contain;` to all the images

Comment: I added an example in codepen. Adding the object-fit didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 1):

The image in your Codepen is set to position: absolute at a fixed width and height of 1200px and 800px, so it doesn’t resize.

As your description of your question talks about resizing the window, I’m assuming you want your main image to scale up and down and for the red dot to stay in the same relative position.

One way to do it using CSS would be to use percentages of the width and height to position the red dot, and use a percentage of the width to scale the size of the dot (using a ratio to set the dot’s height.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-top: 147px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: rgba(83, 39, 39, 0);
}

.largeImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.smallImage {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 57.5%;
    top: 26.17%;
    width: 6.67%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%,50%);
    background-color: rgba(56, 152, 236, 0);
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Circle_Burgundy_Solid.svg/1024px-Circle_Burgundy_Solid.svg.png");
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.smallImage::before {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
    content: "";
}

.smallImage a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" loading="lazy" alt="" class="largeImage">
    <div class="smallImage">
        <a href="#videoPlayer" id="smallBtn"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I included a margin above the image as you had that in your Codepen.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work. Guess I'll have to convert the px to % now :)